# Is it possible to send a dictionary from server to c# client?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, signalr, signalr.client

So I'm able to send simple objects like strings no problem.  I'm also able to send the same dictionary to my javascript client.  However, I can't seem to get my C# client to pick it up. I'm assuming this is because in the javascript client the type being sent doesn't need to be specified, but in C# it does.

Here's the client setup

```
 connection = new HubConnection(ServerURI);
 hubProxy = connection.CreateHubProxy("ControllerHub");
 hubProxy.On<Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, RequestEntry>>("ReceiveTickerStateData", overviewDictionary => receiveTickerStateData(overviewDictionary));
 connection.Start().Wait();
```

Here's the server code that is getting triggered to send the dictionary, but the client never receives it.

```
public void GetTickerStateData()
{
    Clients.Caller.ReceiveTickerStateData(DealTickerState.Instance.GetRequestDict);
}
```

Any insight or ideas are appreciated.  Thanks!

*------------------------Additions*

Further testing has yielded that it is the fact that I'm using a tuple (string, string) as the key for the dictionary.  Apparently the JSON deserializer does not know how to handle this.  Gives me the error:

Could not convert string `(DEFAULT, IDCO)` to dictionary key type

> System.Tuple`2[System.String,System.String]. Create a TypeConverter
>   to convert from the string to the key type object. Path '['(DEFAULT,
>   IDCO)']', line 1, position 19.

I got this by manually serializing and sending the string.
I tried sending a dictionary with just a string as the key and it works fine both as a serialized string and also just as is. (ie signalR automatically serializing)

So now to decide, do I create the type converter? or do I send the data using a simpler collection structure that works.

Comment: Can you add the `RequestEntry` class to your question? It should have the same implementation on both the client and server. Can you also include anything [traced by the SignalR client](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/enabling-signalr-tracing#net_client)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the real answer is Yes, it is possible, but you need to write a custom JSON converter.  You can find more info on that here, though the answer does seem a tad incomplete.

[How to properly serialize tuple as key dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374563/how-to-properly-serialize-tuple-as-key-dictionary)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as JSON. Use JSON.NET, the included JavaScriptSerializer won't work. You can get JSON.NET from NuGet. Convert your dictionary to JSON and send it as a string. On the client-side, just deserialize it using the built-in JSON.parse() method.

Comment: I appreciate the quick reply.  I had tried your suggestion on friday.  Finished doing my testing this morning.  Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create an intermediary type that stores the dictionary during transfer (I use `List<KeyValuePair<T1,T2>>`), it's important that you validate that there aren't any duplicate keys when deserialising this from a client.

```
[Serializable]
public class SerializableDictionary<T1,T2>
{
    public List<KeyValuePair<T1,T2>> SerializedDictionary { get; set; }

    public SerializableDictionary( Dictionary<T1,T2> dictionary )
    {
        if( dictionary != null && dictionary.Count > 0 )
        {
            SerializedDictionary = dictionary.Select( item => item ).ToList();
        }
        else 
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException( "Cannot serialize a null or empty dictionary" );
        }
    }

    public static explicit operator SerializableDictionary<T1,T2>(Dictionary<T1,T2> dictionary) 
    {
        return new SerializableDictionary<T1,T2>(dictionary);
    }

    public static explicit operator Dictionary<T1,T2>(SerializableDictionary<T1,T2> dictionary) 
    {
        if ( dictionary.SerializedDictionary == null ) return null;
        return dictionary.SerializedDictionary.ToDictionary( item => item.Key, item => item.Value );
    }
}
```

This technique wont work for every dictionary (for example, those stored in exceptions) as they can't all be easily suplemented for this service aware dictionary.

Comment: FYI - this technique could also be used to map a Tuple<String, String> to a Generic<T,T> type which likely wouldn't fall into the same securitisation issues.

Comment: This is def a solid alternative, however I found another question answering my exact problem which I have posted below.